# How to filter by column name?

Tags: csvfix

I've a csv file. I'd like to filter it and keep only columns with headers beginning 'hit'. How can I do that?

Small example input:

```
hit1,miss1,hit2,miss2
a,0,d,0
b,0,e,0
c,0,f,0
```

Desired output:

```
hit1,hit2
a,d
b,e
c,f
```

I think I want the [exclude](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/manual/csvfix16/csvfix.html?exclude.html) command but I can't figure out the syntax

Answer (score 0):

The [order](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/manual/csvfix16/csvfix.html?order.html) command will let you specify an inclusive list of column names to be included in the output:

```
csvfix order -fn hit1,hit2 data.csv
```

(I realize I'm late to the party, but maybe this will helpful to the next person.)